# Displaying data from backend in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql

I need to show a value from my table in a label from the front end. I have coded for this as follows.

```
Dim dbl As New vtisDAL.vtisDALDataContext
Dim dsGetFacultydetails = From f1 In dbl.usp_GetFacultyDetails(Val(lblFacultyID.Text)).AsQueryable

For Each entry In dsGetFacultydetails
    lblLeftDate.Text = entry.DateLeft
Next
```

The **DateLeft** column in my table is empty, so I get the following error in the **5th** line of my code:
*Nullable object must have a value.*

How do I fix this?

I tried

```
lblLeftDate.Text = String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.DateLeft)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger? Which line is the error on?

Comment: @mortb, the error is in the code which have mentioned as "tried".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
lblLeftDate.Text = Convert.ToString(entry.DateLeft)
```